# (ng2-charts, angular) Doughnut chart not showing up after AOT? (but filltext is working)

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, angular-aot

The doughnut chart has always worked for me until the last few days. I don't know what changed, but for some reason the actual doughnut doesn't show up after AOT build but does in development mode. I see the difference in the html, but don't know why they are different. The legend and filltext percentage that I draw in the middle of the doughnut still show up, its just the doughnut that isn't visible. I verified that the data being passed in is the exact same. Super weird. don't know why it all of the sudden would've changed. Here are the images of the working and non-working html.

Working:

[image]

Not Working: (After AOT build)

[image]

Notice how the working doughnut has an iframe and the non-visible doughnut does not.

Comment: did you include the stylesheets properly??

Comment: Yeah. Even weirder, I have another doughnut farther down on the same page that is working fine, and the html has the same differences between AOT and local dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the culprit. I had "title: 100%" in the chart options which was causing the graph to not be drawn on the AOT build. I was messing with this when I was figuring out how to get the text drawn in the middle of the doughnut and forgot to remove it. The fact that it worked locally but didn't work after the AOT build doesn't make any sense to me. Removing that option makes it work on both builds though.